# Access violation. RB tree not creating node correctly

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures

I have an RB tree. It correctly inserts the first node at the root, but when stepping through on the debugger it does not create the next nodes, and when trying to set the parent pointer causes an access violation because it failed to create the node whose parent node pointer it is trying to set.

Source code:

core.h

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef CORE_H_
#define CORE_H_

struct node {
public:
    node(double);
    bool color; //false = red, true = black
    double key_value;
    node *left_child;
    node *right_child;
    node *parent;
};

class red_black_tree {
public:
    red_black_tree();
    ~red_black_tree();
    void print_tree();
    void insert(double key);
//  node *search(double key);
//  void delete_leaf(double key);
private:
    node *root;
    node *get_uncle(node *);
    node *get_grand(node *);
    void insert_case1(node *);
    void insert_case2(node *);
    void insert_case3(node *);
    void insert_case4(node *);
    void insert_case5(node *);
    void rotate_left(node *);
    void rotate_right(node *);
    void insert(node *leaf, double key);
    //node *search(node *leaf, double key);
//  void delete_leaf(double key);
    void print_tree(node *leaf);
    void destroy_tree(node *leaf);


};
#endif
```

core.cpp

```
#include "core.h"
#include <iostream>
node::node(double key) {
    left_child = right_child = parent = nullptr;
    color = false;
    key_value = key;
}

red_black_tree::red_black_tree() {
    root = nullptr;
}

red_black_tree::~red_black_tree() {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        destroy_tree(root);
    }

}

void red_black_tree::destroy_tree(node *leaf) {
    if (leaf->left_child!= nullptr) {
        destroy_tree(leaf->left_child);
    }
    if (leaf->left_child != nullptr) {
        destroy_tree(leaf->right_child);
    }
    delete leaf;
}

node *red_black_tree::get_grand(node *leaf) {
    if (leaf->parent != nullptr && leaf->parent->parent != nullptr)
        return leaf->parent->parent;
    else return nullptr;
}

node *red_black_tree::get_uncle(node *leaf) {
    node *g = get_grand(leaf);
    if (g == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    if (leaf->parent == g->left_child)
        return g->right_child;
    else return g->left_child;
}

void red_black_tree::insert(double key) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = new node(key);
        insert_case1(root);
    }
    else insert(root, key);
}


void red_black_tree::insert(node *leaf, double key) {
    //normal recursive binary tree insertion
    if (leaf == nullptr) {
        leaf = new node(key);
    }
    else if (key < leaf->key_value) {
        insert(leaf->left_child, key);
        leaf->left_child->parent = leaf;
        insert_case1(leaf);
    }
    else if (key >= leaf->key_value) {
        insert(leaf->right_child, key);
        leaf->right_child->parent = leaf;
        insert_case1(leaf);
    }

}

void red_black_tree::rotate_left(node *leaf) {
    node *grand = get_grand(leaf), *s_parent = grand->left_child, *left = leaf->left_child;
    grand->left_child = leaf;
    leaf->left_child = s_parent;
    s_parent->right_child = left;
    s_parent->parent = leaf;
    leaf->parent = grand;
}

void red_black_tree::rotate_right(node *leaf) {
    node *grand = get_grand(leaf), *s_parent = grand->right_child, *right = leaf->right_child;
    grand->right_child = leaf;
    leaf->right_child = s_parent;
    s_parent->left_child = right;
    s_parent->parent = leaf;
    leaf->parent = grand;
}

void red_black_tree::insert_case1(node * leaf) {
    if (leaf->parent == nullptr) {
        leaf->color = true;
    }
    else {
        insert_case2(leaf);
    }

}

void red_black_tree::insert_case2(node *leaf) {
    if (leaf->parent->color == true) {
        return;
    }
    else
        insert_case3(leaf);
}

void red_black_tree::insert_case3(node *leaf) {
    node *uncle = get_uncle(leaf), *grand;
    if ((uncle != nullptr) && (uncle->color == false)) {
        leaf->parent->color = true;
        uncle->color = true;
        grand = get_grand(leaf);
        grand->color = false;
        insert_case1(grand);
    }
    else {
        insert_case4(leaf);
    }
}

void red_black_tree::insert_case4(node *leaf) {
    node *grand = get_grand(leaf);
    if ((leaf == leaf->parent->right_child) && (leaf->parent == grand->left_child)) {
        rotate_left(leaf);
        leaf = leaf->left_child;
    }
    else if ((leaf == leaf->parent->left_child) && (leaf->parent == grand->right_child)) {
        rotate_right(leaf);
        leaf = leaf->right_child;
    }
    insert_case5(leaf);
}

void red_black_tree::insert_case5(node *leaf) {
    node *grand = get_grand(leaf);
    leaf->parent->color = true;
    grand->color = false;
    if (leaf == leaf->parent->right_child) {
        rotate_right(grand);
    }
    else
        rotate_left(grand);
}

void red_black_tree::print_tree() {
    print_tree(this->root);
}

void red_black_tree::print_tree(node *leaf) {
    if (leaf != nullptr) {
        print_tree(leaf->left_child);
        std::cout << leaf->key_value;
        print_tree(leaf->right_child);
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "core.h"

int main() {
    red_black_tree tree;
    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(5);
    tree.insert(15);
    tree.print_tree();
    system("pause");
}
```

Ok, so in the example `main()`, the first insertion `tree.insert(10)`, works, it calls the non recursive insert, which determines the root is `NULL` and then sets the root pointer to a new node with the key of 10. The second `tree.insert(5)`, calls the non recursive insert, determines the root exists, and then calls the recursive insert `insert(root, 5)`. This determines that the root is not `NULL`, then goes to the first of the if/else statements, and recursively calls insert like `insert(root->left_child, 5)`. This determines that `root->left_child` is `NULL` and creates a new node at the address for `root->left_child`. The function then goes back up to the original insert call and tries to set the left child's parent to the root, causing an access violation because somehow the left child was not set. Why isn't the insert function setting the node, my debugger says when I step through that the node is created at the last level of recursion using `leaf = new node(5)`, but when it steps back out a level the node is still `NULL` at that address?

Comment: `gdb` is your friend.

Comment: Assigning to a parameter does not change the value of the variable whose value you passed in.

Comment: I dont understand, I did not pass a variable as a parameter, i passed the pointer to the adress of the left child of the root node,

Comment: If i have a struct with a pointer to another struct of the same type, `struct node{node *other;}` and then make an object `node * foo` and do, `foo->other = new node` that would work, and that is essentially what i am doing here.

Comment: @jordan 'leaf = new node(key);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this part of your code:

```
void red_black_tree::insert(node *leaf, double key) {
    //normal recursive binary tree insertion
    if (leaf == nullptr) {
        leaf = new node(key);
    }
    else if (key < leaf->key_value) {
        insert(leaf->left_child, key);
        leaf->left_child->parent = leaf;
        insert_case1(leaf);
    } ...
```

What happens at `insert(5)` in main?
The second if condition succeeds, so you call `insert(leaf->left_child, key)`, but since the leaf here is the root, it does not have any children yet, so we enter again the same method with leaf = nullptr. When `leaf == nullptr` (the first if condition), you just create a node but you do not attach it anywhere to your tree.

This explains why you are having this pattern. Now the whole process of tree creation needs rethinking. The problem is that almost everywhere any node has a non-null left and right children.

Comment: That is where I am confused at, because when it does the call of `insert(leaf->left_child, key)`, with leaf being the root; in the new function call though, leaf now means `root->left_child`,  so shouldn't `new` create a new node at the address of `root->left_child`? I'm just not understanding :/

Comment: @Jordan, look, basically, you are not following an OOP approach. What I advice you is to move the insertion method to the node class itself. The node then checks its left and right children. if it sees that the new key must be at the left subtree, it looks if left_child is null. If so, it creates the node and attaches it as left_child. If not, it hands to new key to the left_child, recursively... you see the logic.

Comment: the problem with that is the insertion cases. They need to be controlled by the exterior tree class because the root node can change depending on insertions and deletions; I would have to create a tree by manually creating the root node and then calling the insert function. With scoping how would i access the new root node since the root pointer i manually made would still refer to the old node, just  one that is no longer the root?

Comment: @Jordan yes this a something you need to deal with. But since you have the parent link, you can always check you old root and navigate through the parent pointers to retrieve the root. This is one solution, among others.